# Как сравнить массив в PHP с неточными значениями и вытянуть похожие?

Tags: php, массивы

Подскажите, как сравнить неточное значение в одном массиве ... если быть точнее - У меня есть старый массив со значениями - который пришёл в "old_files", это названия картинок, которые я вывел с помощью Чекбокса на экран и соответственно передал их значения в checkbox - которые потом в массив попадают с помощью ключей - "XID8QprD_jpg" => "on"
      "jLBF9usM_jpg" => "on"
      "d9ss85Hh_jpg" => "on"

Только я не могу их сравнить функцией - array_key_exists, т.к. ключи поменяли своё название XID8QprD.jpg <-> XID8QprD_jpg , то есть это нижнее подчеркивание не дает мне их сравнить. Подскажите, есть ли какое-то решение данной проблемы?

```
array:12 [▼ 
  "title" => "Девять пяттдесят семь"
  "alias" => "devyat-pyattdesyat-sem"
  "text" => "<p>Девять пяттдесят пятьДевять пяттдесят пятьДевять пяттдесят пятьДевять пяттдесят пятьДевять пяттдесят семьДевять пяттдесят семь</p>"
  "tags_title" => "Вася,петя"
  "addition_products" => "Автобусные туры с ночными переездами - это бич нашего общества!dsadasas,Новый товар 21-02-2020,Новый проверочный товар без ничего"
  "old_image" => "K9eXEi6U.jpg"
  "category_id" => "4"
  "XID8QprD_jpg" => "on"
  "jLBF9usM_jpg" => "on"
  "d9ss85Hh_jpg" => "on"
  "tags_alias" => "vasya-petya"
  "old_files" => array:3 [▼
    0 => "XID8QprD.jpg"
    1 => "jLBF9usM.jpg"
    2 => "d9ss85Hh.jpg"
  ]
]
```

Вот такой код у меня

```
if ($article->file){ 
    $data['old_files'] = explode(',', $article->file); 
    $new_array = []; 
    foreach ($data['old_files'] as $oneFile){ 
        $oneFile = str_replace(".","_",$oneFile);
        if (array_key_exists($oneFile, $data)) { 
            $new_array[] .= $oneFile; 
        } 
    }
```

Comment: ПС - воспользовался str_replace

Comment: если у вас точка перед расширением заменяется на подчеркивание, то замените и сравните. не ясно правда, зачем оно там в принципе заменяется.

Comment: Да, я и воспользовался функцией str_replace, заменяется наверное потому что нельзя передать точки в название ключа . На view -  <input type="checkbox" name="{{$onefile}}"  checked> , где $onefile - имя с точкой (пример - XID8QprD.jpg )

Comment: я бы на вашем месте задумался вообще о том, стоит ли имена файлов как ключи массива передавать. Но код ваш сравнения то где в итоге?

Comment: Вот такой код у меня

if ($article->file){

            $data['old_files'] = explode(',', $article->file);
            $new_array = [];
            foreach ($data['old_files'] as $oneFile){

                $oneFile = str_replace(".","_",$oneFile);
                if (array_key_exists($oneFile, $data)) {
                    $new_array[] .= $oneFile;
                }

            }
        }

Comment: и что в данном коде не работает? помимо сомнительно конструкции `$new_array[] .= ...`, вызывающей синтаксическую ошибку по всей видимости? что вы от него ожидаете то?

Comment: У меня уже всё работает!